# ScalaFX @sfxml Annotation Problems

Tags: scala, scalafx

I am writing a Scalafx application using FXML for the views with the scalafxml library. I am having a ton of trouble getting the classes to compile when using the @sfxml annotation on controller classes. When using them, I keep getting NoSuchMethodExceptions on my constructors as if I have no default constructor but this is definitely not the case. I have been studying this so much that I can only conclude that the problem must be with the library itself. I have followed any information on it as best I know how.

The controller  is for creating a form for the user. Since the "IllegalArgumentException" will be thrown if I try to set the root node's scene twice, I use the root node's id in my constructor for purposes of avoiding the exception.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

My code:

```
@sfxml
class ToolbarController(private val rootLayout: BorderPane) {

  val parent = calcParent

  import javafx.application.Platform
  def newForm = {
    new JFXPanel()
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      override def run() {

        val dialogStage = new Stage {
            scene = new Scene(parent) {
              stylesheets = List(getClass.getResource("/scala/css/form.css").toExternalForm)
            }
        }
        dialogStage.show()
        }
    })
  }


  def calcParent: Parent = {
    val resource = getClass.getResource("scala/form.fxml")
    if(rootLayout.scene == null)
      FXMLView(resource, NoDependencyResolver)
    else rootLayout.getParent
  }
}
```

The FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<BorderPane id="rootLayout"maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="FormController">
   <center>...
```

And my stack trace:

```
Exception in Application start method
Workaround until RT-13281 is implemented: keep toolkit alive
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$11/1268584418.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/patrickslagle/scala/MyApps/PattyCakes/target/scala-2.11/classes/scala/calendar.fxml:7

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:928)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:967)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2711)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
    at Calendar$.delayedEndpoint$Calendar$1(Calendar.scala:15)
    at Calendar$delayedInit$body.apply(Calendar.scala:9)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$$anonfun$init$1.apply(JFXApp.scala:297)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$$anonfun$init$1.apply(JFXApp.scala:297)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$class.init(JFXApp.scala:297)
    at Calendar$.init(Calendar.scala:9)
    at scalafx.application.AppHelper.start(AppHelper.scala:33)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$62/2116169040.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$58/1458556428.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$60/778909025.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$59/1397409682.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: controller.ToolbarController
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:923)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:967)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2711)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
    at Calendar$.delayedEndpoint$Calendar$1(Calendar.scala:15)
    at Calendar$delayedInit$body.apply(Calendar.scala:9)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$$anonfun$init$1.apply(JFXApp.scala:297)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$$anonfun$init$1.apply(JFXApp.scala:297)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$class.init(JFXApp.scala:297)
    at Calendar$.init(Calendar.scala:9)
    at scalafx.application.AppHelper.start(AppHelper.scala:33)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$62/2116169040.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$58/1458556428.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$60/778909025.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$59/1397409682.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: controller.ToolbarController.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:923)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:967)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2711)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
    at Calendar$.delayedEndpoint$Calendar$1(Calendar.scala:15)
    at Calendar$delayedInit$body.apply(Calendar.scala:9)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$$anonfun$init$1.apply(JFXApp.scala:297)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$$anonfun$init$1.apply(JFXApp.scala:297)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scalafx.application.JFXApp$class.init(JFXApp.scala:297)
    at Calendar$.init(Calendar.scala:9)
    at scalafx.application.AppHelper.start(AppHelper.scala:33)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$62/2116169040.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$58/1458556428.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$60/778909025.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$59/1397409682.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last pattycakes/compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last pattycakes/compile:run for the full output.
[error] (pattycakes/compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 46 s, completed May 26, 2016 4:18:42 PM
```

Comment: It is very helpful for answering a question when you provide a complete example [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As the cause if an issue is not always in the snippet you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not instantiate a class annotated with `@fxml` directly. This class is modified by the SFXML compiler macro. It is not shown in the code you posted but somewhere you must instantiate `ToolbarController` to call `newForm`. Posting [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is very important.

Attempting to directly instantiate `ToolbarController` is the most likely cause of the `NoSuchMethodExceptions` as `ToolbarController` constructor is modified by the macro. You need to move methods `newForm` and `calcParent` outside of `ToolbarController`. Only instantiate `ToolbarController` using `FXMLView(resource, ...)`. You also need to add a reference to `ToolbarController`in the FXML file in the top pane:

```
<BorderPane ... fx:controller="mypackage.ToolbarController"> ...
```

With that the `FXMLView` can instantiate `ToolbarController` using only reference to the FXML file. For instance, the instantiation could look like this:

```
import java.io.IOException
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafxml.core.{NoDependencyResolver, FXMLView}

object MyFXMLDemo extends JFXApp {

  val resource = getClass.getResource("/scala/css/form.css")
  if (resource == null) {
    throw new IOException("Cannot load resource: /scala/css/form.css")
  }

  val root = FXMLView(resource, NoDependencyResolver)

  stage = new PrimaryStage() {
    scene = new Scene(root)
  }

}
```

Please take look carefully at the example at https://github.com/vigoo/scalafxml-unit-converter-example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. What I was doing was using FXMLLoader instead of FXMLView when launching my application(the FXML file that uses this as a controller). When I changed it to FXMLView, everything worked. Sorry for not posting a testable version. I am pretty new to Stack Overflow. I will definitely take your advice.